# Why PTRACE_POKEDATA returns I/O error?

Tags: linux, x86-64

I learning usage of ptrace.
I tried following simple example but raises a I/O Error.

I would like to overwrite "Hello, world" (printing string) from other process.
A target program prints "Hello, world" string until stop then I want to change this prints string from another program that use ptrace.

However the ptrace program failed to POKEDATA with I/O Error.
I have no idea why it failed.

I have tried on:
x86_64 Linux 5.11.
AMD Ryzen 7 4750U

ptrace code: (This ptrace code refer from http://0xcc.net/blog/archives/000077.html (Japanese))

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    assert(argc == 4);
    pid_t pid = atoi(argv[1]);
    void *addr = (void *)strtol(argv[2], NULL, 0);
    void *word = (void *)strtol(argv[3], NULL, 0);

    assert(ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, NULL, NULL) == 0);
    wait(NULL);
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_POKEDATA, pid, addr, word) != 0) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 0;

    }
    assert(ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, NULL, NULL) == 0);
    return 0;
}
```

target code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
    while (true) {
        printf("%s\n", "Hello, world");
    }
}
```

A address of target string in target binary (in my environment):

```
Contents of section .rodata:
 2000 01000200 48656c6c 6f2c2077 6f726c64  ....Hello, world
```

exection (shell):

```
./ptrace target_process_id 0x2004 0x60616263   //try to replace from Hell to abcdl
```

Comment: you need an actual address of this string in the process' memory

Comment: @PawełŁukasik How to get it?

Comment: one way is, you can compile w/o PIE and the `objdump` will give you the address

Comment: I tried but it raised following error.  
`relocation R_X86_64_32 against '.rodata' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE`

Comment: how do you compile this?

Comment: I did it like that `gcc --no-pic -o target target.c`

Comment: `gcc -no-pie -o target target.c` works for me

Comment: Oops I was misunderstandeding that pie and pic!  
It works fine for me.  ありがとうございました